# How to add check box in system configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, configuration, system.xml

How do you add a check box in the system configuration & how do you save that check box value in Database?

```
<terms translate="label">
    <class>terms-conditions</class>
    <frontend_type>checkboxes</frontend_type>
    <validate>required-entry</validate>
    <frontend_model>mymodule/system_config_form_terms</frontend_model>
    <sort_order>15</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</terms>
```

**Terms.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Adminhtml customer grid block
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class NameSpace_Mymodule_Block_System_Config_Form_Terms extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $html = "
       <input type='checkbox' class='required-entry' name='terms' value='1'> Terms and Conditions (<a href='#'>Click Here</a>)";
        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add a checkbox? What do you have right now? Is it for a custom module's configuration? What did you already tried to do in the `system.xml`? Please give us more explanation and code examples of what you want and what you already have tried...

Comment: I edited Question Please check

Comment: wow only 9 views and someone is already trying to close this?

Comment: sr_magento : What someone already trying to close ?

Comment: uhm, why not just use the default dropdown functionality for yes/no field? these are already all over the system configuration.

Comment: I want checkbox to use terms & Condition Agree.its not fullfill with dropdown

Comment: Did anyone found the feasible solution for this

Answer (score 1):

**The following doesn't work. It seems we can't set a value via system.xml for the checkbox.**

Magento has two different checkbox types:

- checkbox
- checkboxes

I think you want the first, therefore you have to change the type:

```
<terms translate="label">
    <class>terms-conditions</class>
    <frontend_type>checkbox</frontend_type>
    <validate>required-entry</validate>
    <frontend_model>mymodule/system_config_form_terms</frontend_model>
    <sort_order>15</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</terms>
```

Comment: I am doing same thing. But my check box value is not saved in database. :(

Comment: Please open a question, add your system.xml

Comment: please check my code .. " http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144453/adding-checkbox-in-system-configuration-is-not-working"