# Adding Checkbox in system configuration is not working

Tags: configuration, checkbox, frontend-model

I want to add single check box in my extension like below.

[image]

Please check my system.xml

```
<config>
    <sections> 
      <mymodule>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label" module="paygate">
                    <label>General settings</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                      <visible_on_frontend translate="label">
                        <label>Visible on Front-End</label>
                        <frontend_type>checkbox</frontend_type>
                        <frontend_model>mymodule/system_config_form_frontendavail</frontend_model>
                        <sort_order>22</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </visible_on_frontend>
                  </fields>
                </general>
            </groups>
      </mymodule>
  </sections>
</config>
```

Frontendavail.php

```
<?php
class Namspace_Mymodule_Block_System_Config_Form_Frontendavail extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field  
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $html = "
           <input type='checkbox' class='required-entry' name='terms' value='1'>";
        return $html;
    }
}
```

After doing this check box is display but nothing is happens. Not saving data in database.

Comment: If this is your complete system.xml Please read http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration/

Comment: please check my complete system.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about this but your input name is wrong.
It should be in this format `groups[general][fields][terms][value]`.
That structure is needed in order to read the values properly and store them in the database.
**[EDIT]**

Checkboxes are a bit strange.
If you don't check them, no value is sent via post and the way the system configuration section works for magento it will ignore the not checked field.
You should try as much as possible to avoid checkboxes. Use yes/no selects instead.
But if you really want to use the checkbox, me your `_getElementHtml` method look like this:

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $html = "
       <input type='hidden' name='groups[general][fields][terms][value]' value='0'>
       <input type='checkbox' class='required-entry' name='groups[general][fields][terms][value]' value='1'>";
    return $html;
}
```

Adding a hidden input with the same name before the checkbox will ensure that something is sent via post even if you don't check the checkbox. When checking the checkbox, the hidden input value will be ignored.

Comment: can you please help me in detail ?

Comment: Take a look at the form fields added without a `frontend_model`. Any field from the core. And you should see the way that the `name` attribute looks like.  That structure is needed in order to read the values properly and store them in the database.

Comment: thank you :)  it works and is saving in database. but if i unchecked check box then there is no effect is come in database. instead of this it saving 1 every time (whether check box is checked or not. )

Comment: see my edit. Maybe it helps.